# yarn redirect track certain npm packages in version control

Tags: npm, version-control, yarnpkg

I need to install apollo-engine for my cloud instance. This repository has dependencies:

```
"optionalDependencies": {
    "apollo-engine-binary-darwin": "0.2018.4-86-gf35bdc892",
    "apollo-engine-binary-linux": "0.2018.4-86-gf35bdc892",
    "apollo-engine-binary-windows": "0.2018.4-86-gf35bdc892"
}
```

Those dependencies are super slow to install on my instance. Is there some way to redirect those repos to a disk location, or track them in my version control and do something like 
`yarn install --<option to exclude apollo-engine-binary-*>`

Answer (score 0):

If using Docker or any other containerization system, you should be able to use a custom image providing `yarn` with those packages preloaded as [cache](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/cache/).

Comment: sorry. no Docker